# How to see pixel density (Retina) in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, screen-size

In Google Analytics, "Screen Resolution" is a default dimension under Audience > Technology > Browser & OS reports, but pixel density is nowhere to be found.

How can I use Google Analytics to determine how many of my visitors are using Retina or other high-def displays?

Answer (score 5):

Google Analytics does not support pixel ratio by default but you can add it with script for a custom variable. See https://github.com/tysonmatanich/GetDevicePixelRatio for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Lets turn that around and ask why would you care?

Assuming it's to determine if image/icon size is an issue, I've recently tossed all the multiple-resolution icons and replaced them with SVG graphics. Logos and larger non-vector images are all 2x size in a plain <img> tag.

Positive side effects are faster loads (the SVG is in the main style sheet) and easier modification. Haven't encountered any negative side effects yet.

If IE8 compatibility is required I will run one sprite file - make one page with all your icons and you can just screencapture it for instant sprites.

Comment: You should care as if there's no high pixel ratio users, then sending everyone 2x sized images is a grand waste of everyone's time and resources. Also if everyone happens to be using 3x pixel ratio devices, then you still aren't providing full res pictures to your user base.

Comment: Some typefaces (esp if you are considering system fonts to maximize application performance) look great on retina displays, but terrible on standard resolution displays. We're considering this very thing for github.com right now.

Comment: How do you convert photos to SVG?

Comment: I care because I have some scaled down images that just look bad on 1x screen due to antialiasing and it's a pain to fix. So I want to see how many users are actually on 1x screens to see if it's worth fixing it or not. The image looks great on 2x screens because you just don't see the differnce.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can look at the Operating System of your users, if it's an iOS or Macintosh you can assume they use retina displays.

Comment: Is this true of all Macs? At what point did this become always true?

Comment: it's NOT true on all Mac OS - for example, Macbook Air has no retina display and is a popular laptop.