# How to track pixel density with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I originally had it setup like [How to see pixel density (Retina) in Google Analytics?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58221/how-to-see-pixel-density-retina-in-google-analytics) with Universal Analytics by setting custom demisions.

However, we recently had to switch to tag manager. Currently a bit lost on how to replicate the same actions as before.

Can anyone provide insight or a tutorial as how to set this in GTM?